# convert D2D1::Matrix3x2F to XMMATRIX

Tags: c++, matrix, directx

I have some text that I am drawing to the screen... but because of the requirement to use D2D1::Matrix3x2F as the translation, it is not being drawn where I really want to draw it... Everything else is using XMMATRIX... **Is there a way to convert these 2?**

Text transformations stuff:

```
D2D1::Matrix3x2F screenTranslation = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(
    Window::width - hud->textMetrics.layoutWidth,
    Window::height - hud->textMetrics.height
    );

d2dDeviceContext->SetTransform( D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation( hud->starEndPositionX, hud->starEndPositionY ) );
```

Everything else is done like this:

```
XMMATRIX rot = XMMatrixRotationY( a->rot );
XMMATRIX trans = XMMatrixTranslation( a->x, a->y, 0.0f );
XMATRIX final = rot * trans;
```

So the issue is that all my coordinates are based off of 0,0,0 being centre of screen whereas the text is like 0,0 is top left. 1920 x 1080 is bottom right. Boooooo.

Side note: My 3d set up of transformation is like so:

```
// trans
matView = XMMatrixOrthographicLH( Window::width, Window::height, -1.0, 1.0 );

//projection

float fieldOfView = ( float )PI;
float screenAspect = Window::width / Window::height;

matProjection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( fieldOfView, screenAspect, -1.0, 1.0 );
```

So to summarise... is there a way to either convert some 2d coordinates to 3d coordinates, or even visa versa so that when i can put my 3d coordinates into the 2d 3x2F translation instead?

**D2D1::Matrix3x2F to XMMATRIX**

Comment: And what is you question?

Comment: Yea, i'm finding it hard to understand what to ask aswell... i basicqally have this dilemma where im using 2ddevice to draw text and 3ddevice for everything else... so somehow i want my 2d text to be drawn to the screen using the 3d device coordinates (which are orthographic and 0,0 is the middle of the screen)